# Does org-mode support callouts like asciidoc?

Tags: org-mode

I wonder if org-mode has a feature like asciidoc callouts, and if so what is the syntax?

Below is a explanation on what the callouts are and how it all looks when rendered

[image: AsciiDoc callout example]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Org Mode does support callouts.  The documentation for it is hidden in the [Literate Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) section of the manual, but does in fact apply to source code blocks.

Unlike AsciiDoc, Org Mode with Org Babel keeps the code and the documentation cleanly separated.

The example below uses Org Babel to generate a Ruby code file using the `:tangle` keyword.  The Org export functions will generate HTML, much as AsciiDoc does.

Use the `(ref:name)` syntax to make callouts.  The documentation can appear anywhere outside the code blocks.  You can create the links easily using `C-c C-l` or `M-x org-insert-link`

The `-r` option in the code block strips the (ref:name) comments from the tangled source code.

The `-n` option adds line numbers when exporting.

```
* My example
   #+begin_src ruby -r -n :tangle mysample.rb
     puts 'Hi!'          # (ref:puts)
     print 'ram:'        # (ref:print)
     name = gets.chomp   # (ref:gets)
     puts "Hi! #{name}"  # (ref:deref)
   #+end_src

   Code explanation:
   + [[(puts)]] puts the string to stdout
   + Remember the [[(print)][print]] function does not output a newline
   + In line #3, [[(gets)][gets]] reads from =stdin=
   + Finally, [[(deref)][#{name}]] replaces the variable =name= with its value
```

When you export the above Org Mode file to HTML and open it in a browser using the export dispatcher (`C-c C-e h o) you can hover over the links to highlight the relevant code line.

[image: screenshot of exported HTML with hover]

Comment: Just when  I think org-mode and org-babel cannot get more awesome they surprise me again.